# Show $|x(t)|$ is strictly decreasing for $t>0$ for the initial value problem $\dot{x} = -x^{3}, x(0)=1 $

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Solving the inital value problem gives me $x(t)=\frac{1}{(2t+1)^{1/2}}$ which is clearly striclty decreasing as $(2t+1)^{1/2}$ is strictly increasing. However is it possible to just say it's strictly decreasing as the derivative  $\dot{x} = -x^{3}$ is strictly decreasing for postive x, if not how would I solve this without having to explicitly solve the inital value problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you show that exactly like that. As $x(t)=0$ is a solution, and the right side is locally Lipschitz, the uniqueness theorem implies that the zero solution can not be crossed, *all solutions have a constant sign.*

Now the initial value $x(0)=1$ fixes the sign for the solution of the given IVP as positive, and the formula for the right side gives then the sign of the derivative  as negative.